# How to replace a windows directory with backlashes using Regex?

Tags: regex, string, windows, directory, path

I have some .xml files with this shape

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
-<annotation>
<folder>Flowers</folder>
<filename>A Basket of Flowers 435814.jpg</filename>
<path>D:\ML\MetImages\IsHighlight\Dataset\Flowers\A Basket of Flowers 435814.jpg</path>
```

I'm trying to use Python's regex to replace the path in each file with another one:

```
"<path>D:\ML\Object_Detection\ObjectTrain\Data\train\images\A Basket of Flowers 435814.jpg</path>"
```

But since Window's paths uses backlashes, it recognizes the following character as a special one, therefore printing the following error:

```
article_path = re.sub(r"<path>D:\ML\MetImages\IsHighlight\Dataset\Tree", "<path>D:\ML\Object_Detection\ObjectTrain\Data\train\images", article_path)
error: bad escape \M at position 8
```

Even when trying double backlash it gives the same error:

```
article_path = re.sub(r'<path>D:\\ML\\MetImages\\IsHighlight\\Dataset\\Tree', '<path>D:\\ML\\Object_Detection\\ObjectTrain\\Data\\train\\images', article_path)
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\gputensorflow\lib\sre_parse.py in parse_template(source, pattern)
   1014                 try:
-> 1015                     this = chr(ESCAPES[this][1])
   1016                 except KeyError:

KeyError: '\\M'
```

What options do i have to replace the directory paths? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What version of python are you using @juanikok ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you realize that your regex looks for the sub-directory `\Tree` while your sample contains `\Flowers` - or is this part of the path variable?

Try it like this:

```
regex = r"<path>D:\\ML\\MetImages\\IsHighlight\\Dataset\\[^\\]+"
test_str = "<path>D:\\ML\\MetImages\\IsHighlight\\Dataset\\Flowers\\A Basket of Flowers 435814.jpg</path>"
subst = "<path>D:\\\\ML\\\\Object_Detection\\\\ObjectTrain\\\\Data\\\\train\\\\images"    
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/SKC6mr/2/)